# Wrong resolution on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, display, monitor

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my system.
My graphics card is an NVidia 8800GTS. For some reason ubuntu detect that my screen resolution is up to 1024x1280. I have already installed the NVidia drivers with no success. The resolution went to 640x480. I tried to use solutions with xrandr but no success. My monitor is shown that is connected on port DVI-I-0. How can I fix that issue? My monitor works fine on Windows and on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Is your videocard up-to-date?

Try the following:
You can install/update all video drivers with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```